# How to turn to US characters

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)

I need to change strings that have accents E.G: Casá to become Casa. Is there an easy way to do it with PHP? Thanks

Comment: And another good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if iconv doesn't work well for your purposes, strtr will replace characters with replacement characters that you assign.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

```
<?php
//In this form, strtr() does byte-by-byte translation
//Therefore, we are assuming a single-byte encoding here:
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
?>
```

some user example...

```
$GLOBALS['normalizeChars'] = array(
    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 
    'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 
    'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 
    'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 
    'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 
    'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 
    'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'
);

return strtr($toClean, $GLOBALS['normalizeChars']);
```

Comment: `'ß'=>'Ss'` Doesn't make sense to me. It should be `'ß'=>'ss'`.

Comment: that is some user example from the php documentation for the function. i didn't write it.

Comment: don't get me wrong, I gave you your upvote, so I like your post. It's an alternative solution to the problem which is worth something at least. Another thing I should mention (for posterity), is that `'Æ'=>'A'` should be `'Æ'=>'AE'` and `'æ'=>'a'` should be `'æ'=>'ae'`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86

Answer (score 5):

```
$text = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

Comment: This is really the best way to do it. Lots of hackish ways out there, make sure to try this first.

Comment: This works quite well. See here: http://ideone.com/2ZPVE

Answer (score 0):

"á" and "a" are different letters; one is not simply "a with an accent". You need to define the mapping that you want between characters. Then perhaps make an array of suitable character replacements, and apply them in a loop over the input string.

Answer (score -2):

you can use `htmlentities()` and `preg_replace()` (to select the second character).
Example:

```
echo preg_replace(
'/&([a-zA-Z])(uml|acute|grave|circ|tilde|cedil|ring);/',
'$1',
htmlentities("Hélicoïdal"));
```

Comment: `htmlentities()` for normalizing accented characters into their base versions?

Comment: This is a horrible idea.

Comment: @Pekka: yes, see example

Comment: Ohh! Interesting. This isn't bad at all.

Comment: @Pekka: I vaguely remembered it at first, that's why it was so unclear. I'm trying to find where I read this.

Comment: @greg0ire yeah. But there might be Unicode Umlaut characters that don't translate into a word entity, but a number - I find it interesting that HTML entities have this kind of regularity to them, but the `iconv()` solution is probably more reliable

Comment: @Pekka: I agree, but since I found this solution interesting too (and I didn't know the `iconv()` solution), I decided to post it. I don't understand all these downvotes.

Comment: I downvoted you and I'll tell you why: it's a hack and nowhere near a complete solution.  Characters like Ð and Ž fail, and certainly every ligature would fail. And they will fail in the worst way: silently. No error would be generated from your algorithm missing these characters, and then you'd end up with crap like `&AElig;` and `&ETH;` in your output and never know it w/o manual inspection.  Not to mention false positives - what if the input is already HTML with legitimate entities that are to be preserved?

Comment: @Peter Bailey: this is much more interesting than your previous comment, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Too many years of doing this have made me crusty and weary of "clever" solutions, because they are *very rarely* "good" solutions.