# Removing Various symbols like Â é

Tags: php

OK I have read many threads and have found some options that work but now I am just more curious than anything...

When trying to remove characters like: Â é as google does not like them in the XML product feed.

Why does this work:

But neither of these 2 do?

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^[:print:]]+/", ' ', $string);

$string = preg_replace("/[^[:print:]]/", ' ', $string);
```

To put it all in context here is the full function:

```
        // Remove all unprintable characters
        $string = ereg_replace("[^[:print:]]", ' ', $string);
        // Convert back into HTML entities after printable characters removed
        $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        // Decode back
        $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        // Return the UTF-8 encoded string
        $string = strip_tags(stripslashes($string));
        // Return the UTF-8 encoded string
        return utf8_encode($string);
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed the code-block that works?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that code doesn't work is because it removes characters that are not in the posix :print: character group which is comprised of printable characters. á É, etc are all printable.

You can find [more about posix sets here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Also, removing accentuated characters might not always be the best option... Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php) for alternatives.