# Special characters search mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mongodb match accented characters as underlying character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707671/mongodb-match-accented-characters-as-underlying-character)

I'm from a country where we have more characters than English alphabet. 
Basically what I want to do is:

I have word **ščumnik**, and I want to search in database for **šcumnik**, **scumnik**, **sčumnik**,

```
š=s
ž=z
č=c
é=e
...
```

I want to ignore everything above letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Question on how to remove diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/javascript-remove-accents-in-strings) at StackOverflow

[Article with listing in JavaScript](http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/)

After diacritics is removed, you can use the resulted value for example for searching and index building.