# Searching a UTF8 string with special characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Ok, so I have a collection, Users, that goes like:

```
[
 {
  name: 'André Alçada Padez',
  ...
 }, 
 ...
]
```

I want to find my user, in that collection, using the filter:

```
db.users.find({name: /andre/i})
```

or

```
db.users.find({name: /alcada/i})
```

how can i let mongo know, that `"c"` can be a `"ç"` or `"e"` can be a `"é"`?

thanks

Comment: Normally a safer way is to downgrade the characters to their plain English edition and then store that in a separate field

Comment: thanks, i thought of that, but i think that would be a little overkill. Anyways, if you put that as an answer, and i get no more answers in 24 hours, i will accept it

Comment: this was already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707671/mongodb-match-accented-characters-as-underlying-character with an interesting idea in the question itself