# MongoDB php accent search utf8

Tags: mongodb, search

i have a collection in mongodb

`array( 'name'=>'Péter' )`

when i query `$this->mongo_db->like('name', 'Péter', 'i', true, true)` so success but

query `$this->mongo_db->like('name', 'Peter', 'i', true, true)` no result

i used codeigniter alex bibie

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution to this problem is to store a second array with the normalized strings, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500455/893113).

Comment: oh it's mean i must store as array('name'=>'Péter','name_no_utf8'=>'Peter') and my database will to distended when i have collections . Some other ideas ....

Answer (score 0):

e and é are two totally different characters. Although you may want some sort of character folding for names, in most other scenarios you would freak out if "e" == "é".

MongoDB does't support collations or automatic converting of characters so this is not going to work. You'll have to normalize it yourself if you want such matching.

Comment: ok perhaps i'll storage more 1 array() accent names and no accent names in my db... this is also a solution but my db will to distended.... huh(mysql very easy for this occasion but mongodb nothing to do so i hate mongo but i still have to work with it) ...