# How to search for accented characters in mongodb collection using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

MongoDB treats É and E as two separate things, so when I search for E it will not find É.

Is there a way to make MongoDB think of them as the same thing?

I am running

```
var find =Users.find();
var re = new RegExp(name, 'i');
find.where('info.name').equals(re);
```

How do I match for strings containing accented characters and get the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not supported in `mongodb` and i doubt if it will be in the near future. What you could do to overcome is store a different field in each document containing the **simple** form of each name, in **lowercase**.

```
{
  info:{"name":"Éva","search":"eva"};
}

{
  info:{"name":"Eva","Search":"eva"}
}
```

When you have your document structure this, you have a some advantages,

You could create an index over the field `search`,

```
db.user.ensureIndex({"Search":1})
```

and fire a simple query, to find the match. When you search for a particular term, convert that term to its simple form, and to lower case and then do a find.

```
User.find({"Search":"eva"});
```

This would make use of the index as well, which a `regex` query would not.

See Also: [Mongodb match accented characters as underlying character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707671/mongodb-match-accented-characters-as-underlying-character)

But if you would want to do it the hard way, which is **not** recommended. Just for the records i am posting it here,

You need to have a mapping between the simple alphabets and their possible accented forms. For example:

```
var map = {"A":"[AÀÁÂÃÄÅ]"};
```

Say the search term is `a`, but the database document has its accented form, then, you would need to build a dynamic regex yourself before passing it to the `find()`, query.

```
var searchTerm = "a".toUpperCase();
var term = [];
for(var i=0;i<searchTerm.length;i++){
    var char = searchTerm.charAt(i);
    var reg = map[char];
    term.push(reg);
}

var regexp = new RegExp(term.join(""));

User.find({"info.name":{$regex:regexp}})
```

Note, that the depicted example can handle a search term of `length > 1` too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you suggest how to do using regex for a quick fix?

Comment: @dreamhigh, I have updated my answer. But that is not the way you need to handle the situation. you need to restructure and re-index your documents for better performance. You should follow the first approach.