# Mongoengine: Match accented character based as underlying character

Tags: python, string, mongodb, mongoengine

Related: [How to do this in MongoDB db.foo.find() syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707671/mongodb-match-accented-characters-as-underlying-character).

Let's suppose I have a model

```python
class Foo(Document):
    name = StringField()
```

And the database state for the collection is:

```
[{"name":"Jesús"},{"name":"Jesus"}]
```

I want a query that match both documents, i.e. search, but with diacritics normalized, something like:

```
Foo.objects.filter(name__icontains="jesus")
```

Is there a way to do this directly in mongoengine?

Answer (score 0):

With python, you can `import unidecode`, and then compare all accents to normal text as,

```
from unidecode import unidecode
li = [ ]
for entry in Foo.objects:
    if unidecode(entry.name) == "Jesus":
        li.append(entry)

# now li has your filtered entries
```

Alternatively, you can do

```
from unidecode import unidecode
li = [ entry for entry in Foo.objects if unidecode(entry.name) == "Jesus" ]
```

> Note: You have to install `unidecode` using `pip install unidecode`.

**EDIT:** The following code works as expected,

```
>>> unidecode('Jesús')
Jesus
```

Comment: That's ok, I know about `unidecode` lib... but using your first snippet yields  `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

Comment: @NicolasMartinez: I'm sorry, I thought it is valid to place functions inside `.filter` method. But, I was totally wrong. I've now edited my answer. I don't think that you can do it with `.filter` method anymore. No?

Comment: No, and this method is extremely less performant, at least in my typical data

Comment: I don't know about your data, but I think my method should be performant atleast, as per [this article](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#accessing-our-data). However, I will try to improve myself, if you'll explain me more about your data.