# How to preg_replace everything but _-/

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to replace special characters with the ones they're based on in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php)

I need to sanitize a string which will include special characters (foreign language keyboards, etc.) and I need to change them to say "ä => a" while not removing characters like "_", "-" and "/".

Comment: How is your rule defined for removing `special characters`?  There are literally hundreds of characters in Unicode that have various markings on them, not to mention non-latin-alphabet characters.  How are those to be handled?  If you do generate an exhaustive list, you may find the [`strtr`](http://us3.php.net/strtr) command useful for this purpose.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? Googling **[regex replace everything except](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=regex+replace+everything+except)** produces quite a lot of results.

Comment: I'm doing something like '/(à|á|â|ã|ä|å|æ)/' => 'a'. Yes I have tried, wouldn't come here otherwise. @GabiPurcaru Not a duplicate, as you see I didn't ask only how to replace characters, but asked how to replace characters with leaving some out.

Comment: @qalny Since `_-/` aren't based on any other characters, they won't be replaced using any of the methods in the other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'à|á|â|ã|ä|å|æ');

a|a|a|a|a|a|ae
```

No need to regex. The right tool for the right job.

Comment: Sometimes the best answer to a regex question is to not use regex at all :)

Comment: +1 for a succinct answer (which also happens to be correct) :-)