# php-script outputs xml file but breaks on special characters

Tags: php, xml

I have created this php script, to create an xml-file from my database:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "root";
$database = "flexapp";

$charToReplace = array("é", "è", "ê");
$charReplacements = array("e", "e", "e");

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database.");

$query = "SELECT * FROM artists";
$artist_result = mysql_query($query, $linkID) or die("Data not found.");

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$xml_output .= "<artists>\n";

for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($artist_result) ; $x++){
    $itemrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($artist_result);
    $xml_output .= "\t<artist>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<id>" . $itemrow['pk_artist_id'] . "</id>\n";
    $itemrow['artist_name'] = str_replace($charToReplace, $charReplacements,         $itemrow['artist_name']);
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<name>" . $itemrow['artist_name'] . "</name>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<picture>" . $itemrow['artist_pic'] . "</picture>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<twitter>" . $itemrow['artist_twitter'] . "</twitter>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t</artist>\n";
}
$xml_output .= "</artists>\n";
echo $xml_output;
?>
```

I try to replace characters like é en ê to e.

But it gives this error in the browser:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 23 at column 9: Encoding error
```

This is the xml that is outputted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<artists>
<artist>
    <id>1155</id>
    <name>Have Heart</name>
    <picture>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/29086375.jpg</picture>
    <twitter></twitter>
</artist>
<artist>
    <id>1156</id>
    <name>Dead Swans</name>
    <picture>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/4781939.jpg</picture>
    <twitter></twitter>
</artist>
<artist>
    <id>1157</id>
    <name>Nirvana</name>
    <picture>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/3991355.jpg</picture>
    <twitter></twitter>
</artist>
<artist>
    <id>1158</id>
    <name>Touchter>
</artist>
```

But the last one (the name in the database is Touché Amoré) should be like all the rest, but somehow the strings aren't being replaced.

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php) maybe it will help

Comment: One thing I've fallen over with doing something similar is the MySQL connector - by default, even if the engine is storing the string in utf-8, the connector pulls it out in iso-8859-1 unless you set the charset to the connector. See mysql_set_charset() @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php If you've got the XML file in utf-8 and the database is in utf-8 you _shouldn't_ need to convert the 'é' type characters to 'e'

Comment: Tried this, but it doesn't help.

Comment: expanded on it as a full answer - feel free to ignore if you've sorted it though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be an issue with encoding the data before printing. Try using `utf8_encode()` and `htmlentities()`

```
function xmlencode($data) {
    $data = utf8_encode($data);
    $data = htmlentities($data);
    return $data;
}
```

and then

```
...
$xml_output .= "\t\t<picture>" . xmlencode($itemrow['artist_pic']) . "</picture>\n";
...
```

Comment: `<name>
<![CDATA[ Touch&Atilde;&copy; Amor&Atilde;&copy; ]]>
</name>`

Close, it creates the full xml-file this time, but as you can see, still not complete ok.

Comment: By removing the line `$data = htmlentities($data);` it works, thank you!

Comment: great, glad that helped :) So you used it in combination with the CDATA[] from rifat? That should do it

Comment: yeah, don't use htmlentities(); HTML entities !== XML entities; technically in standard XML there are only 5 entities. Conveniently, they're the same as used by htmlspecialchars() so that's a better function to use. There's a slight proviso with utf8_encode() as well - it **only** converts from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 (I've fallen over that with the € symbol and Windows-1252 before).

Comment: I faced a similar problem and i solved it by running the below query before outputting the xml data: **mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just wrap name variable with CDATA like

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml, charset=utf-8');
```

---

```
<name><![CDATA[Some very wired name]]></name>
```

And, If I were you then I will use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to generate the XML.

Comment: Should I put it like this:
    "\t\t<name><![CDATA[" . $itemrow['artist_name' . "]]]></name>\n" or like this "\t\t<name>" . <![CDATA[$itemrow['artist_name']]]> . "</name>\n"

Comment: Like the first one but you put and extra `]` in the end.

Comment: `"\t\t<name><![CDATA[" . $itemrow['artist_name'] . "]]></name>\n"`

Comment: `<name><![CDATA[Touchue Colors]]></name>` This is my output now, still not working.

Comment: I get the same one as in the first post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5720/discussion-between-rifat-and-veltar)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the characters are saved as entities, which is why it will not replace and will 'destroy' your XML output.

Your scripts works like a charm over here and outputs as expected. Will you check your database via phpmyadmin if the saved value contains é instead of é? In that case you should decode the entities first to the characters they represent: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Also, like stated by @Rifat, you can wrap the values in CDATA: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA

Answer (score 0):

If your database is in utf-8 and your XML file is in utf-8; you shouldn't need to do any conversion for "foreign" characters like é.

First off, ensure your database tables are stored in utf-8 and then fix your XML file to utf-8...

```
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type:text/xml;charset=utf-8"); //  <- add this line
```

Next - make sure that your MySQL connector is retrieving the utf-8 data from the database in utf-8 (it doesn't by default).

```
$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database.");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8"); //  <-- add this line; NOTE MySQL doesn't use the hyphen in the utf-8 string
```

In theory now, all your é, ê and ñ (and so on) characters *should* appear properly inside the XML document without any conversions or CDATA parsing required.

The only characters you'll need to convert are, IIRC, the same as those converted by htmlspecialchars namely `<`, `>`, `&` and (optionally) quotes and apostrophes.