# Converting special characters at variable for URL usage

Tags: php, sql, url-rewriting, preg-replace, sanitization

So, this is the problem, i think everything is ok with this function, but URLs like:

reparações

are showing always as "reparaa-a-es".

The expected result should be "reparacoes"

> EDIT:
>
> So, the solution was simple, it seems php has a native function that
>   does what i need:

```
rawurlencode ( string $str )


function generateSafeUrls($url = '') {
    ## normalize accented characters
    $url = strtr($url, "\xA1\xAA\xBA\xBF\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3\xC5\xC7\xC8\xC9\xCA\xCB\xCC\xCD\xCE\xCF\xD0\xD1\xD2\xD3\xD4\xD5\xD8\xD9\xDA\xDB\xDD\xE0\xE1\xE2\xE3\xE5\xE7\xE8\xE9\xEA\xEB\xEC\xED\xEE\xEF\xF0\xF1\xF2\xF3\xF4\xF5\xF8\xF9\xFA\xFB\xFD\xFF", "_ao_AAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUYaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuyy"); 
    ## make sure its only english and dashes
    $url3 = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", "_", $url);
    ## return safe url
    return($url3);
}
```

What should be the problem?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Unrelated - chuck in a `strtolower()`

Comment: I can't understand your question, how should URLs like `reparações` be shown?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?  Unicode is certainly valid in URLs.  And if you are trying to sanitize a query string, use urlencode() or a variation.

Comment: Similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on (using UTF8 decoding rather than trying to declare all the hexadecimals):

```
function generateSafeUrls($url = ''){
   $bad = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ';
   $good = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr';  
   $url= strtr(utf8_decode($url), utf8_decode($bad), $good);
   return preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+/", "_", $url);
}
```

However, as Conrad Shultz notes in comments, you don't necessarily need to do this... simple `urlencode()`ing should be fine... if you want cleaner looking urls, you should run the `preg_replace` so that the URLs don't have `%20` etc, and you should probably `strtolower()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$GLOBALS['normalizeChars'] = array(
'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ð'=>'Dj','Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 
'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E', 'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 
'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U', 'Ú'=>'U', 
'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss','à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 
'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c', 'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 
'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o', 'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 
'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y', 'ƒ'=>'f'
);

function cleanForShortURL($toClean) {
    $toClean     =     str_replace('&', '-and-', $toClean);
    $toClean     =    trim(preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $toClean));//remove all illegal chars
    $toClean     =     str_replace(' ', '-', $toClean);
    $toClean     =     str_replace('--', '-', $toClean);

    return strtr($toClean, $GLOBALS['normalizeChars']);
}
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
function slug($string, $replacement = '-') {
    $map = array(
        '/à|á|å|â/' => 'a',
        '/è|é|ê|ẽ|ë/' => 'e',
        '/ì|í|î/' => 'i',
        '/ò|ó|ô|ø/' => 'o',
        '/ù|ú|ů|û/' => 'u',
        '/ç/' => 'c',
        '/ñ/' => 'n',
        '/ä|æ/' => 'ae',
        '/ö/' => 'oe',
        '/ü/' => 'ue',
        '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
        '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
        '/Ö/' => 'Oe',
        '/ß/' => 'ss',
        '/[^\w\s]/' => '',
        '/\\s+/' => $replacement,
        "/$replacement+/" => $replacement
    );
    return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
}
```

[Source](http://ittyb.it/u4c38a585)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to transliterate characters. Perhaps something like this could help:

```
/**
 * Strips non-url friendly characters from $string
 *
 * @param string $url string to be checked
 * @return string cleaned url
 */
function generateSafeUrls($url)
{
    $url = iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', $url);

    return preg_replace('~[^a-z0-9_\.-]|\s+~i', '_', $url);
}
echo generateSafeUrls('reparações'); 
// reparacoes
```