# Replace special characters before the file is uploaded using PHP

Tags: php, special-characters

I was wondering if it is possible to change the name of the file to be uploaded. I mean what I am trying to do is that, the user uploads a file which may have some special characters like special characters in some European languages.

What I am planning to do is that before using the move_uploaded_file command is it possible to change/preg_replace the special characters with normal characters, so that the file is uploaded and stored with the new name which has only normal characters.

Comment: It's possible, yes. What have you tried?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
// Get the original file name from $_FILES
$file_name= $_FILES['file']['name'];

// Remove any characters you don't want
// The below code will remove anything that is not a-z, 0-9 or a dot.
$file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $file_name);

// Get the location of the folder to upload into
$location = 'path/to/dir/';

// Use move_uploaded_file()
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location.$file_name);
```

Comment: @472084, You have solved my so long problem with special characters in Zip file and under sub directories or files. Great. :)

Comment: this works great, but you have to add the dot too for the file extension. 
$file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", "", $file_name);

Comment: it works but didn't change/rename the file name on path location

Comment: Note that depending on your use case, you _may_ wish to remove the dots as well, just in case someone tries `../../../passwd`. It probably doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 3):

try to use this bro

```
   $result = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);
```

to know more visit [how to replace special characters with the ones they're based on in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original filename for an uploaded file from `$_FILES`, and you can create your "special" version by replacing characters in it with [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) (which sounds as the best match for this case), `str_replace`, `preg_replace` or any other string processing function.

The best approach depends on what *exactly* you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, write a simple function `strip_special_chars()` to replace characters you want in a string

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$name = strip_special_chars($tmp_name);
move_uploaded_file($name, "path/to/dir/");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a function for special characters like this:

```php
function safename($theValue)
{
    $_trSpec = array(
        'Ç' => 'C', 
        'Ğ' => 'G', 
        'İ' => 'I',
        'Ö' => 'O', 
        'Ş' => 'S', 
        'Ü' => 'U',
        'ç' => 'c', 
        'ğ' => 'g', 
        'ı' => 'i',
        'i' => 'i',
        'ö' => 'o', 
        'ş' => 's', 
        'ü' => 'u',
    );
    $enChars = array_values($_trSpec);
    $trChars = array_keys($_trSpec);
    $theValue = str_replace($trChars, $enChars, $theValue); 
    $theValue=preg_replace("@[^A-Za-z0-9\-_.\/]+@i","-",$theValue);
    $theValue=strtolower($theValue);
    return $theValue;
}
```

Be carefull about allow . for file extension.

And then change your original temp file name,

```php
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetFile = safename($targetFile);

$location = 'path/to/dir/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $location.$targetFile);
```