# Server problems with æ ø å

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I have a UNIX server running. I have a program, that uploads images to my server.

but I'm having some problems with these chars: <kbd>`ø`</kbd> <kbd>`æ`</kbd> <kbd>`å`</kbd>

In my program I used

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

**Example**:

I upload an image called `påske.png`

On my server I can see the picture is called `påske.png`

In my database, the name `påske.png` is also saved.

if I then manually tries to see my picture, I get an error

I type: `www.myserver.com/uploads/påske.png`

```
Error: /uploads/pÃ¥ske.png was not found on this server.
```

Comment: Check the charset the webserver (Apache ?) is using.

Comment: hi. I don't know, since I am no longer using my own local apache server. I wrote to the people who run my server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shoulnd't save the special chars direct as filename. Give them a new name like a **timestamp** or replace the spacial chars with the english equivalent.

What you have is normal then your server / Webserver has a default charset like **UTF-8** for example. Special chars in Linux are displayed in this character Set.

**Edit:**

[Replace special characters before the file is uploaded using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838994/replace-special-characters-before-the-file-is-uploaded-using-php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the advice. I think I will follow it. I tried this: $overskrift_tmp = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $overskrift);.
When I type in: etætoøtreå.
I get this: etaeligtooslashtrearing.
Can't i just get ettotre ?

Comment: Okay, the admin of my server told me just to avoid æ ø å, so I am using your suggestion :) Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use this [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/115-PHP-Convert-special-string-into-normal-string-.html) and change the file name during upload

```
* normal - converts each special character (áéíÁÈÒÖ) to their 
normal character (aeiAEOO)

string $class->normal(string string);

Example: 
print $strings->normal("faço áeéíàÒ");
# will output: faco aeeiaO
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Could also have used this yes, but I got the other thing to work :)

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function de_danishify_filename_on_upload($filename) {
if("do a check") return $filename; // Checks to see if a string is utf8 encoded

$filter_chars = array(
    // Character mapping from UTF-8 characters to ASCII characters. 
    chr(195).chr(134) => 'AE',  // &AElig; to Ae
    chr(195).chr(166) => 'ae',  // &aelig; to ae
    chr(195).chr(152) => 'OE',  // &Oslash; to OE
    chr(195).chr(184) => 'oe',  // &oslash; to oe
    chr(195).chr(133) => 'AA',  // &Aring; to AA
    chr(195).chr(165) => 'aa'   // &aring; to aa
);
$translated = strtr($filename,$filter_chars); // Translate characters

return $translated;
}
```