# PHP - By changing .zip file name, does not changes its path while reading file from it

Tags: php, utf-8, zip

I have following `.zip` file with following name `Café, Room service, deli'very.zip`. I am able to change `.zip` file's name by removing special characters.

```
$string = str_replace(array(","),array(""),$string);

$accent   = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕƒ';
$noaccent = 'SOZsozYYuaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRra';
$string = strtr(utf8_decode($string),utf8_decode($accent),$noaccent);
$string = strtr($string, $accent, $noaccent);
```

Now what the problem is when I read files from `.zip` it refers to it's original .zip name and not the new changed name what I did.

**Edit:**

I could able to change `.zip` filename from `Café, Room service, deli'very.zip` to `Cafe Room service, delivery.zip` but when reading from .zip file, say `1.jpg` then it's reading path like `Café, Room service, deli'very/1.jpg`.

Can anybody focus on it?

Edit:

I am using following code for .zip file

```
$zip = zip_open($_FILES['tmp_name']);
$zipEntry = zip_read($zip);
zip_entry_name($zipEntry);
```

Comment: Do you mean paths in the zip refer to the old path? - that is encoded in the zip rather than based on the filename.

Comment: @John3136 Yes. While reading files from Zip it's referring old path (.zip filename) and not what I have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am come with solution for a question for which I was looking since long time.
Here my solution.

```
$_FILES['name'] = str_replace("'","_",$_FILES['name']);
$_FILES['name'] = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.\s\/]/", "", $_FILES['name']);
```

Where I am truncating any special characters and replacing them with nothing `""`. Allow Ascii characters, space and slack (forward). And after doing this I am properly able to read the directories, sub directories and files under the `.zip` file with special characters (in any language). I specially appreciate a fellow friend which has provided the [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838994/replace-special-characters-before-the-file-is-uploaded-using-php?answertab=active#tab-top) for other [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838994/replace-special-characters-before-the-file-is-uploaded-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

The path is encoded as part of the zip data. It is not based on the zip filename.
Changing the filename alone will not change paths within the zip file.

Comment: Then, How can I change path for all files under that `.zip` file so that they all can acquire the new changed name of `.zip` file?

Comment: Possibly args to zip to tell it where to unzip to? Hard to say since we don't know how you are calling zip...

Comment: I appreciate your nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The zip file is the zipped up contents of a directory.

That directory is included inside the zip file and is not generated from the name of the zip file so you could call the zip file. foo.zip and it would still contain the same files and directories. The zip file was just called the same as the included directory, but they are not the same thing.

The easiest way to change the contents of the zip file is to

- Unzip it
- Rename the directory
- Zip up the new directory

Comment: You cannot change the contents of a book by changing its name. Even if your zip file was called foo.zip INSIDE the zip file there is still a directory called "Café, Room service, deli'very"

Comment: I appreciate your nice explanation.