# replace special characters with normal characters in php

Tags: php, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to replace special characters with the ones they’re based on in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php)

Here is sample code:

```
$code="CSC113α";//other codes PHY123β,MAT324δ

    ////return last character of the code
    $lastchar=substr($code, -1);

    // returns rest code without last character..
    $rest = substr($code, 0, -1);  

    //Make standard course_ID with a,ß..
    switch ($lastchar)
    {
    case '&alpha;':{
      $lastchar='A';
      $id=$rest.$lastchar ;
      $full_course_id=$id;
      break;
    }
    case '&beta;':{
      $lastchar='B';
      $id=$rest.$lastchar ;
      $full_course_id=$id;
      break;
    }
    case '&delta;':{
      $lastchar='D';
      $id=$rest.$lastchar ;
      $full_course_id=$id;
      break;
    }
    default:
      $full_course_id=$code;
    }
```

Here I try to replace α,β,δ with A,B,D...This code is not working..Here variable code values comes from another script with special characters..Here I want to replace those characters with normal characters.. I want get final out put like 'CSC113A'..but this switch code doesn't work for me...please help me to do this...thxx in advanced....

Comment: How can you compare a single character against strings like `&alpha;`?

Comment: your cases won't match `$lastchar` as it is a single character and they are not.

Comment: @jack: α=&alpha; that's why put it there.....becoz using α for case code still not working frnd....

Comment: `mb_substr()` is what you need for this.

Comment: @dnagirl : I saw this link..but I couldn't fix my problem frnd....

Comment: @ DaveRandom : how can I use it frnd  mb_substr() function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use the function `str_replace`? I've done a test and it works for me!

```
<?php
$code="CSC113α";
$full_course_id = str_replace(array('α','β', 'δ'), array('A', 'B', 'D'), $code);
```

Comment: yes frnd ..this code is working perfectly...thanxx so much....u all are doing great help for the upcoming coders,....