# In PHP, how do I take a string with all kinds of characters and turn it into a string with just A-Z and 0-9 characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to replace special characters with the ones they’re based on in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php)

I have a string that looks like this:

```
ABCÇĆDEFGHÎIïJ123450086
```

In PHP how can I make it appear as:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ123450086
```

without having to manually replace each character not needed. Can I use some kind of RegEx for this? How?

I just want A-Z and 0-9, no other foreign characters (as in, remove them).

Comment: Your question is _extremely_ unclear.  Do you want to remove the characters? Convert them to non-accented form? What about `א`?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1891343/948301

Comment: You should look at the `strtr()` function, here is an example function someone has posted. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php#90925

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use character classes:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w\d]/', '', $string);
```

Replaces all occurences of characters which are not (`[^]`) alphabetic (`\w`), nor a digit (`\d`) with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

A nice function :

```
/**
 * Strip accents
 *
 * @param string $str string to clean
 * @param string $encoding encoding type (example : utf-8, ISO-8859-1 ...)
 */
function strip_accents($str, $encoding='utf-8') {
    // transforme accents chars in entities
    $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, $encoding);

    // replace entities to have the first nice char
    // Example : "&ecute;" => "e", "&Ecute;" => "E", "Ã " => "a" ...
    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z])(?:acute|grave|cedil|circ|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);#', '\1', $str);

    // Replace ligatures like : Œ, Æ ...
    // Example "Å“" => "oe"
    $str = preg_replace('#&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig);#', '\1', $str);
    // Delete else
    $str = preg_replace('#&[^;]+;#', '', $str);

    return $str;
}

// Example
$texte = 'Ça va mon cœur adoré?';
echo suppr_accents($texte);
// Output : "Ca va mon coeur adore?"
```

Source : http://www.infowebmaster.fr/tutoriel/php-enlever-accents

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove them, You can use preg_replace to replace all characters that are not in the ranges a-z, A-Z and 0-9 with '';

Otherwise use the translation technique given in the other thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use regular expressions.

`preg_replace('/^[A-Za-z0-9]/', '', $some_str)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a whitelist:

```
$input = 'ABCÇĆDEFGHÎIïJ123450086';
$filtered = preg_replace("~[^a-zA-Z0-9]+~","", $input);
```

Comment: That would remove the extended characters, not replace them with their ASCII "equivalents".

Comment: It works!! I've tried it.

Comment: Yes, it *works*, but it does not do what the OP is asking. OP wants something that will turn `ABÇ` into `ABC`. Your answer will turn it into `AB`.

Comment: @ithcy: you have to read the question. There aren't 3 `C` in `ABCDEFGHIJ123450086`.

Comment: I did read the question. You are misunderstanding. Try your answer on the string `'ABÇ'`. It will become `'AB'` because you are *stripping out* the extended characters instead of *replacing* them with ASCII. Get it?

Comment: @ithcy: No you are wrong. Run my script! The result is: `ABCDEFGHIJ123450086` and this is what he was looking for.

Comment: @ithcy: yes, that's exactly what's being asked.  Example input: `CÇĆ`; Example result: `C`.  Only the `C` got kept.

Comment: Sorry but I am not wrong. Try your answer on `'ABÇ'`. Just those 3 characters. Not `'ABCÇĆDEFGHÎIïJ123450086'`. Now do you understand? The expected result would be `'ABC'`. Do you get `ABC`? No you don't. You get `AB`.

Comment: Better yet, just try it on `Ç`. You will get an empty string, where the OP wants `C`. Now do you understand??

Comment: @ithcy: don't be bullish

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to be! I just got frustrated. My apologies :)

Comment: It will be really funny if the OP comes along now and says "actually I did want the empty string" :)