# Why Normalizer::normalize (PHP) doesn't work?

Tags: php, normalization, intl

I'm trying to normalize strings with characters like 'áéíóú' to 'aeiou' to simplify searches.

Following the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890854/how-to-replace-special-characters-with-the-ones-theyre-based-on-in-php) I should use the `Normalizer` class to do it.

The problem is that the `normalize` function does nothing. For example, that code:

```
<?php echo 'Pérez, NFC: ' . normalizer_normalize('Pérez', Normalizer::NFC) 
    . ' NFD: ' .normalizer_normalize('Pérez', Normalizer::NFD)
    . ' NFKC: ' .normalizer_normalize('Pérez', Normalizer::NFKC) 
    . ' NFKD: ' .normalizer_normalize('Pérez', Normalizer::NFKD)?>
<br/>
<?php echo 'aáàä, êëéè,' 
    . ' FORM_C: ' . normalizer_normalize('aáàä, êëéè', Normalizer::FORM_C )
    . ' FORM_D: ' .normalizer_normalize('aáàä, êëéè', Normalizer::FORM_D)
    . ' FORM_KC: ' .normalizer_normalize('aáàä, êëéè', Normalizer::FORM_KC)
    . ' FORM_KD: ' .normalizer_normalize('aáàä, êëéè', Normalizer::FORM_KD)?>
```

shows:

```
Pérez, NFC: Pérez NFD: Pérez NFKC: Pérez NFKD: Pérez
aáàä, êëéè, FORM_C: aáàä, êëéè FORM_D: aáàä, êëéè FORM_KC: aáàä, êëéè FORM_KD: aáàä, êëéè
```

What is supposed normalize must do?

---EDITED---

It is stranger. When copy and paste the result from web browser, while in editor and original page I can see:

```
FORM_D: aáàä, êëéè
```

in the stackoverflow question page I can see (just in Code Sample mode):

```
FORM_D: aáàä, êëéè
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found on [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/l-vim-script-1/#values-and-variables): (the linked document has different wording, the old one never exists anymore)

> Unicode and internationalization is a large topic, but you should know
>   at least one more important thing. For historical reasons, Unicode
>   allows alternative representations of some characters. For example, á
>   can be written either as one precomposed character á with the Unicode
>   code point U+00E1 or as a decomposed sequence of the letter a (U+0061)
>   combined with the accent ´ (U+0301). For purposes of comparison and
>   sorting, two such representations should be taken as equal. To solve
>   this, the intl library provides the Normalizer class. This class in
>   turn provides the normalize() method, which you can use to convert a
>   string to a normalized composed or decomposed form. Your application
>   should consistently transform all strings to one or the other form
>   before performing comparisons.

```
echo Normalizer::normalize("a´", Normalizer::FORM_C); // á  
echo Normalizer::normalize("á", Normalizer::FORM_D); // a´
```

So eliminating accents (and similar) is not the purpose of `Normalizer`.

Answer (score 13):

`Normalizer` with `FORM_D` can split the diacritics out from the base characters, then `preg_replace` can eliminate the diacritics:

```
$string = 'áéíóú';
echo preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u', "", Normalizer::normalize($string , Normalizer::FORM_D));
//aeiou
```

Comment: Very nice, I had done it before in Javascript using this approach. And it worked for PHP too.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)`.

http://php.net/manual/function.iconv.php

Be careful with `LC_*` settings! Depending on the setting the transliteration might change.

Comment: To remove accents is better to use: `iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text);`

Comment: @StefanoColetta for some reason I can't get it to work. Trying on a sample string `jakaś`gives me `jaka?`

Answer (score 1):

For a function that actually removes the accents, the best that I have found so far is in the wordpress core:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1127
remove_accents($string)

(Note I have filed a bug against it in order for them to take an updated version that I provided which documents each character and how it is tranlsted. so it may change in the future)

Comment: One could just copy-paste function, no matter what framework it is form. Wordpress took care to cover most of possible multi-lang cases, and in this case should be considered as valid answer to given issue.